# swift 3 Avplayer layer not visible while playing same video second time

Tags: ios, swift3, avplayer

In my application I have used `AVPlayer` to play videos, If we play a video and go bock to previous page video is playing in backgraound well but if we play the same video again we have to show continuation of the video and it should not begin from start , Here I can able to set slider position according to the video duration but the screen not showing video content sound is coming.

For first time to play any video i called below method

```
  func setup()  {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(videoString as NSString, forKey: CurrentURL)
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
        let targetTime:CMTime = CMTimeMake(0, 1)
        mediaPlayer.seek(to: targetTime)
        mediaPlayer.pause()

        print("Video URL \(videoString)")
        let url = NSURL(string: videoString)
        let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url! as URL)
        mediaPlayer=AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
        let playerLayer=AVPlayerLayer(player: mediaPlayer)
        playerLayer.frame =  self.view.bounds
        playerLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        //playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResize
        playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)


        AppDelegate.shared().showLoading()
        videoView.isHidden = false
        mediaPlayer.play()
        let duration : CMTime = mediaPlayer.currentItem!.asset.duration
        let seconds : Float64 = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration)
        videoSlider.maximumValue = Float(seconds)
        videoPlayButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "Pause"), for: .normal)
        videoPlaying = true
        //Adding Default Periodic Observer On Player
        mediaPlayer.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1, 1), queue: DispatchQueue.main) { (CMTime) -> Void in
            if mediaPlayer.currentItem?.status == .readyToPlay {
                AppDelegate.shared().removeLoading()
                self.videoSlider.value = Float(CMTimeGetSeconds(mediaPlayer.currentTime()))
                let currentTime : Int = Int(CMTimeGetSeconds(mediaPlayer.currentTime()))
                let minutes = currentTime/60
                let seconds = currentTime - minutes * 60
                self.durationLabel.text = NSString(format: "%02d:%02d", minutes,seconds) as String

            }
        }
    }
```

If user plays same video second time i'm checking current url which is stored in userdefaults if it is playing same video i did like following

```
    let runningSrtring = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: CurrentURL) as! NSString
    if runningSrtring.isEqual(to: videoString) {

        //self.view.layer.sublayers?.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperlayer() }
        videoPlayButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "Pause"), for: .normal)
        let duration : CMTime = mediaPlayer.currentItem!.asset.duration
        let seconds : Float64 = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration)
        self.videoSlider.value = Float(CMTimeGetSeconds((mediaPlayer.currentTime())))
        videoSlider.minimumValue = 0
        videoSlider.maximumValue = Float(seconds)
        let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: mediaPlayer)
        playerLayer.frame =  self.view.frame
        playerLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        //playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResize
        playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect

        self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
        mediaPlayer.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1, 1), queue: DispatchQueue.main) { (CMTime) -> Void in
            if mediaPlayer.currentItem?.status == .readyToPlay {
                self.videoSlider.value = Float(CMTimeGetSeconds((mediaPlayer.currentTime())))
                let currentTime : Int = Int(CMTimeGetSeconds(mediaPlayer.currentTime()))
                let minutes = currentTime/60
                let seconds = currentTime - minutes * 60
                self.durationLabel.text = NSString(format: "%02d:%02d", minutes,seconds) as String
            }
        }
    }
```

But the lauer is not showing video content if i play same video again , here if the user play same video which is already running it should continue from current duration instead of restarting

Comment: instead of remaking another player, just keep a var to the player and use player.replaceItem

Comment: I'm not remaking another player here, I'm using only one player which is declared in AppDelegate class, My requirement is First i have played a video and come back to previous page then selected the same video to play here the video should not start from beginning it should play from its current position. By using above code i can able to play video from its current position but the video content not visible for second time i can able to hear the sound, Help me why the video content is not visible for second time.

Comment: If your videoplayer is in appDelegate then you have more problems, why is it not in your VC ? theres not nearly enough code here to help im afraid

Comment: In my application if a video is playing in one screen then i have to show a bottom view in every screen with slider duration lable and play button , i.e i have to access player in every screen while its playing audio or video for this i have declared AVPlayer in AppDelegate class